# 静的サイトをWordpress化する方法を教えてください

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress化する方法はどれが正解なのか迷走し始めたため、
皆様のご意見を伺いたく質問させていただきました。

#### 前提

- 効率（スピード）重視
- CSSでデザイン調整が必要になる程度のサイト作成
- 大規模なサイト構築ではなく、中小・個人経営向けのサイト作成
- CMSでブログ・ニュース等の投稿機能の実装。レイアウト変更等はCMSでできなくてもOK

#### 私の認識

まず私の認識には、Wordpress化には大きく分けて下記の2つの手順しか存在していません…

1. 静的サイトを作成→Wordpress化
2. 既存のWordpressテンプレートから作成→CSS等のデザイン調整

#### お聞きしたいこと

- Wordpress化手順について
  →上記の手順で行っている場合は効率的にする裏技があれば教えていただきたいです！
  →「そもそもそれ以外にいい方法あるのに…」といったご意見もいただけると助かります…

初歩的な質問となり大変恐縮ですが、ご回答いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: ホームページビルダー等のホームページ作成ツールでもWordpressサイトの作成はできますよ。

Comment: 投稿ブロックをphpで定義できるプラグインを使って簡単に記事投稿できるに作成しています。

Comment: @池田茂樹 様　回答ありがとうございます。ホームページ・ビルダーでも作成できるのは初耳でした！

Comment: @yyz 様　回答ありがとうございます。PHPを定義できるプラグインですか…差支えなければプラグイン名を教えていただけますと幸いです。

Comment: phpでCustom Blocksが定義できるプラグインです。プラグイン名は：lazy-blocksですが、 ある程度phpを理解していないと 使えないプラグインと思われる物です。

Comment: yyz様 ありがとうございます！lazy-blocks調べてみます！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

静的なHTMLが大量にあって、Wordpress化したい、というときには、
あたしの場合は、適当なページを作って、そのページにアクセスしたら`wp_insert_post`を走らせるようにして流し込んだりしてます。
・`foreach`と`glob`でHTMLファイルをディレクトリから取得
・`file_get_contents`でHTMLを読み込む
・`preg_match`で必要な部分を抜き取る
・`wp_insert_post`で流し込み
・必要ならば`update_post_meta`でカスタムフィールドに流しこむ
という感じです。
ディレクトリも再現するとなるとちょっと手間がかかりますが、一度組んでおくと次からも使えるので便利です。
最後はヘッダーとフッターを再現してあげて、CSSでちょっと調整って感じでしょうか。
上に挙げた関数を見てハードルが高いなと思う場合は難しいかもしれませんが、あんまり詳しくなくても関数を調べながら追っていくとできてしまいそうな気がします。（あたしもそのクチでした。）